# IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Here is my code

```
if (player != null) {
    if(player.isPlaying()){
        player.pause();
        player.stop();
    }
    player.release();
}
```

and here is error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
at com.mindefy.sindhipathshala.RecViewAdapter.mediafileRelease(RecViewAdapter.java:234)
at com.mindefy.sindhipathshala.SectionFruits.onBackPressed(SectionFruits.java:252)
```

I am a beginner in Android and i am very confused with the lifecycle of a `MediaPlayer`.

This is a function in an adapter that is called from `onBackPressed()` function of another `Activity`. `player` is a class variable.

I am releasing this `MediaPlayer` in same file as

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    player = MediaPlayer.create(activityContext, soundId);
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: Looks like player has been recently released. Method isPlaying() returns true only after start() has been called. Check if you have called .reset() or .release() in your code before making a call to player.isPlaying() which is throwing IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is you don't keep track of the state of your `MediaPlayer` instance.

Before calling `isPlaying()` you only perform a `null` value check, although `player` can still be released (but not `null`).

**Calling `isPlaying()` on a released `MediaPlayer` instance will result in an `IllegalStateException`**.

To avoid this, you could for example set `player` to `null` when you release it:

```
player.release();
player = null;
```

Or you could use a `boolean` flag to keep track of its state:

```
boolean isReleased;

// ...

player.release();
isReleased = true;
```

So you could check for this flag when necessary:

```
if (player != null && !isReleased) {
    if(player.isPlaying()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(don't forget to set it to `false` when appropriate)

Comment: Very nice and simple!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to earthW0rmjim: I was facing the same issue (some audios didn't reproduce because of an ilegal state exception). What I found is that I was reseting my audio object on a callback. So, I was setting player.setDataSource(url) before I reset my object, because the callback was doing it after. My solution: player.reset() on the try / catch block of setDataSource and prepareAsync.

```
try {
        player.reset(); //Important line
        player.setDataSource(url);
        player.prepareAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Error playing file " + url, e);
    }
```

And look at the callback:

```
public void finishedPlayback(){
    player.reset(); //Executing after the try / catch (sometimes)
}
```

Comment: Save my world  \o/

Comment: :) @icaro glad to hear that.