# How to fix IllegalStateException in Mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I have a listview and MediaPlayer created in OnItemClick.

```
        listSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Song song = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, song.getmSongResourceId());
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.release();
            }
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener () {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mPlayer.start();
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    controller.show(0);
                }
            });

            mPlayer.start(); //error here
            controller.show(0);
        }
    });


@Override
public void start() {
    mPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlayer.pause();
    controller.hide();
}
```

When ckick on item activity close. Here is logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1228)
    at com.....MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:432)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:314)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1162)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java:432 is `mPlayer.start();`.
What is `IllegalStateException`, and how can fix it? You may say my post is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158194/illegalstateexception-in-mediaplayer) post duplicate, but I'm not sure how to apply it solutions to my code.

Comment: You should call `release()` when you're done, not before `start()`

Comment: @bwt, you mean in onCompletion method?

Comment: as soon as you know you will not use it anymore. Basically you can't do anything with a mediaplayer instance once it has been released

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener () {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        mp.pause();
        controller.show(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: why should it fix a problem?

Comment: the same question